# What is wrong with this django view?

Tags: python, django

in this django view I'm trying to do the following:

- Check if there is a "chartentry" with today's date
- In that case, do not substitute the description with the new value, but just append it to the old value

I can't for the life of me figure out why it is always repeating twice the new value (e.g. the description ends up as `"newvalue;newvalue"` instead of `"oldvalue;newvalue"`.

```
@login_required
def chartentry_create(request, chart_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Chart, id=chart_id)
    todaysentry = obj.chartentries.filter(
        created_at__gte=timezone.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0),
        created_at__lte=timezone.now().replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59),
    ).first()
    # if it's today's entry, append data to it instead of creating a new one
    if todaysentry:
        form = ChartEntryForm(request.POST, instance=todaysentry)
    else:
        form = ChartEntryForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # if it's today's entry, append description
        if todaysentry:
            form.instance.description = (
                todaysentry.description + ";" + request.POST["description"]
            )
        form.instance.chart = obj
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "Entry updated successfully")
    else:
        for error in form.errors:
            messages.error(request, form.errors[error])
    if is_ajax(request):
        context = {"chart": obj}
        return render(request, "chart_entries_by_patient_partial.html", context)
    else:
        return redirect("chart-detail", patient_id=obj.patient.id)
```

Comment: It's hard to help with the details, you are giving. Why would "description" in the POST data be different from description of today's chartentry?